# Rotation of RotatedRect in OpenCv

Tags: java, opencv

I am using OpenCV in Java. I have two concerns, one of them is crucial for me:

I have RotatedRect and I want to Rotate this RotatedRect and get new RotatedRect or just Rect (in case of rotating strict vertical or horizontal). let it say:

```
RotatedRect rr = ...; //existing RotatedRect 
RotatedRect result = rotateRotatedRect(rr, angle);
```

I need smth for rotateRotatedRect() method.

My second question is, I want to scale RotatedRect (scaling from the center or from one of the corner is fine)

Can you suggest me anything. I can implement this, but requires time and logiic. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://www.docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.11/org/opencv/core/RotatedRect.html):

> Class **RotatedRect**
>
> - double angle (the rotation angle in a clockwise direction)
> - Point center (the rectangle mass center)
> - Size size (width and height of the rectangle)

To achieve rotation and scaling, you can directly change the `RotatedRect` variables.

```
RotatedRect rr = ...; // existing RotatedRect 
rr.angle += 30;       // rotates 30 degrees clockwise
rr.size.width *= 2;   // scales width by 2
rr.size.height *= 2;  // scales height by 2
```

Comment: Thank you. I've just looked for source code, and you are right! I haven't thought it might be like this. I was expecting calculation on native level.

Comment: @RustamIS :) You can move (translate) the `RotatedRect` by moving the `center` too.